# How to verify jwt access token has required scope

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a built in way in .net core 3.1 to Verify that the JWT token present in the request has a Required Scope.

A sample of jwt data I already have from our Identity Server:

```
{
  "user_id": "12345",
  "scope": "test1"
}
```

I have already seen the article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore

But this is specific for azure-ad and it requires that the Scope claim is named "scp" instead of "scope".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you configure the authorization handler by defining various policies to control the access to your API based on the data provided in the access token.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for more details.